# How to load JSON data in Cocos2d-X 3.0 in javascript

Tags: javascript, cocos2d-x

How would one load a javascript structure (object or array) from a file in Cocos2d-X 3.

My `res/test.json`:

```
{
    version:"1.0",
    data:"this is some data."
}
```

I'm able to load the file content like so:

```
var data = fileUtil.getStringFromFile('res/test.json');
cc.log(data);
```

What is the best way to load the javascript structure from the string? Is there a function in cocos2d-x to do this directly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "standard" `JSON.parse` works:

```
var fileUtil = cc.FileUtils.getInstance();
var data = fileUtil.getStringFromFile('res/test.json');
var jData = JSON.parse(data);
```

But note all attribute names must be passed in quotes, otherwise the parser will fail. `res/test.json` must then look like this:

```
{
    "version":"1.0",
    "data":"this is some data."
}
```

Comment: @TravisG: The module I wrote is not used on mobile, but there is little chance this standard functions would be missing in the mozilla runtime used by the mobile Cocos2d C++ version. It's the nearly the same as the desktop version.