# Cocos2d 2.1.4 js HTML5 load text/string/json

Tags: javascript, json, loading, cocos2d-js

I have been trying to upload a large string to my project in order to implement it as a matrix, but I keep hitting a wall trying to load a text file or json into my HTML5 project. I have seen that in 3.0 you can do it with cocos2d, but is there any way with 2.1?

example of what I need to do, done in 3.0:
[cocos2d-js: How to load a JSON file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24359297/cocos2d-js-how-to-load-a-json-file)

(really UGLY solution I know I can do is to write it into the javascript)

I don't know how many javascript packages I can install since I stil want to be able to port to android and other platforms with cocos2d (I guess that is a secound question)

Comment: By "hitting a wall" do you mean there's a filesize above which the loading fails but it works if it's under it? Also, is there a reason why you are not migrating to v3?

Comment: I used 2.1.4 because I found a example and some tutorials that could teach me some basic things about game development, ended up going away from it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ended up moving to HTML5 instead of cocos2d since it better suited my needs, found that there were no good solutions to a lot of things I needed in cocos2d.

Comment: That's a shame. If you ever want to try again, make sure to use the latest version available and the official docs, that said, you need to know JS beforehand. PS: for the record, [this is how you load JSON data](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20686519/1605873) (the standard HTML way), I thought you were trying that process and it was somehow failing.